basic analysis: prove or disprove: if for all fixed $k\in\Bbb N,\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+k}-a_n|=0$ then $(a_n)_n$ converges
this is a homework question, so any hints are welcome. I tried showing it using the cauchy criterion for convergence of sequences, but I got stuck: For any fixed $k\in \mathbb N$, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n\geq n_0: |a_{n+k}-a_n|<\varepsilon$ then for all $m,n\geq n_0$ and WLOG $m>n$ then for $k=m-n\in \mathbb N$... but it doesn't have to be the same $n_0$ that will make the cauchy criterion work.
I think this might be false, but I cannot find a counterexample. the intuition behind the cauchy sequence convergence is exactly that, because the difference between any two points in the sequence can be arbitrarily small as long as you are after some $n_0$, but this k is fixed which makes it harder.

Please use latex/MathJax in the title.

Consider $\sqrt{n}$. Then $a_n - a_m = \frac{n-m}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{m}}$.

You may see: Property of a divergent sequence ${a_n}$ of positive real numbers satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$

This isn't even true if $(a_n)$ is bounded. For example, $a_n = \sin( \log (n))$ or maybe even $a_n = \sin( \sqrt {n})$ might be counter-examples.

As some have pointed out, this is false. An easy example is $a_n=\log n$. We have
\begin{align}a_{n+k}-a_n &=\log(n+k)-\log n \\\\&= \log\left(1+\frac kn\right)\\\\&\to 0\end{align}
But $\log n\to\infty$
